# Why is R not recognizing the new column I added into my dataframe?

Tags: r, cbind

I am doing time series analysis on oil prices in R. In order to complete one of my modeling tasks, a MONTH column next to the closing price of oil each month was added:

```
df <- cbind(df, MONTH=1:nrow(df))
```

The output was successful and came out to this:

```
    OILSTOCK MONTH
1       1965     1
2       1812     2
3       1492     3
4       1289     4
5       1256     5
```

I then have to take a holdout sample on the last 12 months of the data (there are a total of 108 months), I do so with the following:

```
n_OILSTOCK=OILSTOCK[1:96]
n_MONTH=MONTH[1:96]
```

The command above works as expected for n_OILSTOCK, but for some reason, I get the following error in regards to n_MONTH:

```
> n_MONTH=MONTH[1:96]
Error: object 'MONTH' not found
```

I am unsure why R is not recognizing this new MONTH column as a proper object. Is there an easy way for me to address this? The original data was brought in as .txt format. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

`MONTH` doesn't exist in your environment. It is just a column you created in the `df` Data Frame when you called `cbind(df, MONTH=1:nrow(df))`.

To reference `MONTH` as a column of this dataframe, you can do it this way:

```
n_MONTH <- df$MONTH[1:96]
```

Alternatively:

```
n_MONTH <- df[1:96, 'MONTH']
```

As explained, this is because `MONTH` doesn't exist as an object. You have to reference it by pointing it to the column in your `df` dataframe.

In comparison, `OILSTOCK` actually do exist in your environment, and you're able to perform the subsetting operation without a problem.